# (403) Legacy People API > has not been used in project XXXXXXXX before or it is disabled in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-oauth, google-signin, google-developers-console

I'm using Google Login it was working few months back but now when i try to log in it gives me following error :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Google_Service_Exception
>
> Message: Error calling GET
> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me: (403) Legacy People API
> has not been used in project XXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable
> it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXX
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

On visiting the link it show

```
"Failed to load."
"There was an error while loading /apis/.....googleapis.com/overview?project=<project_id>. Please try again."
```

I have enabled `People API` also

but still getting the same error message

Api i have enabled :

[image]

Any solution please Thanks

Code:

```
<?php 
require_once('Google/autoload.php');

class Google {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($url){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
        $this->CI->config->load('google_config');
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setClientId($this->CI->config->item('google_client_id'));
        $this->client->setClientSecret($this->CI->config->item('google_client_secret'));
        $this->client->setRedirectUri($url[0]);
        $this->client->setScopes(array(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
            )
        );
  

    }

    public function get_login_url(){
        return  $this->client->createAuthUrl();

    }

    public function validate(){     
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
          $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();

        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
          $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
          $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
            $person = $plus->people->get('me');
            $info['id']=$person['id'];
            $info['email']=$person['emails'][0]['value'];
            $info['name']=$person['displayName'];
            $info['link']=$person['url'];
            $info['profile_pic']=substr($person['image']['url'],0,strpos($person['image']['url'],"?sz=50")) . '?sz=800';

           return  $info;
        }


    }

}
```

> GoogleConfig.php

```
$config['google_client_id']="XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$config['google_client_secret']="XXXX";
```

Controller :

```
$this->load->library('google',array(base_url().$this->config->item('google_redirect_url_signin')));
$this->data['google_redirect_url_signin']=$this->google->get_login_url();
```

View:

```
<button onclick="location.href ='<?=$google_redirect_url_signin?>';" class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">
                                    Login with Google
                                    </button>
```

Comment: You want us to tell you how to fix GoogleApi internal error?

Comment: @Justinas this is a configuration issue with a project on Google cloud console.   This is an error the developer must fix.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code i would like to see what call you are making exactly?

Comment: @NicoHaase please bare with me, give them a chance to add the code i need.

Answer (score 0):

## API disabled.

> (403) Legacy People API has not been used in project XXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting

This error message is caused this api is not enabled in your project  on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) .

Why it is not enabled is a question I can not answer.

To fix it go to [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) under library

[image]

search for people api

[image]

Click on it

[image]

then click enable button, mine shows manage because it is already enabled.

## failed to load

The failed to load error can mean two things.

1. someone deleted the project you are using on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) which you are using to run this aplication.
2. Someone has removed your access to the project on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) in which case find out who the admin is and have them fix the error above.

## api

The error message has me a little confused. It seems to imply that you are using this endpoint `https:// www.googleapis.com/plus /v1/people/me`.   I thought all of the google plus api endpoints were renamed to the people api years ago.  You should be using [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)  Which makes me wonder if google just disabled something on you that your still using.

## scopes

Please try and remove these scopes from your app

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

They are old google plus scopes and do not exist now.   profile and email should be enough.

Comment: @Dalm To Thanks for the answer i have enabled this api today but getting same error will it take time to activate, i have added screenshot in my question can you please check

Comment: How old is this app?  Can you edit your question and include the code you are using to authorize your application.     And the call you are making that's throwing the error.

Comment: @DalmTo App is around 3 years old and i have added the code in my question Can you please check

Comment: When was the last time you uploaded the php client library?

Comment: try and remove the plus scopes

Comment: @DalmTo in 2019 i created this app then only uploaded client library, i have removed ` "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",`  these two scopes but same facing same issue

Comment: did you enable the people api like i mentoned?

Comment: @DalmTo Yes i have enabled the people api today, added screenshot also in the question

Comment: try changing Google_Service_Plus to Google_Service_People.   If that doesnt work i will give it a go in the morning.